# What does this "direct" mean here?

Tags: grammar

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sapir%E2%80%93Whorf_hypothesis#cite_note-46) **We handle even our plain English with much greater effect if we direct it from the vantage point of a multilingual awareness.**

What does this "direct" mean here?
It doesn't make much sense. Does it mean "Look"?

Comment: "It doesn't make much sense."? Have you looked up **all** possible meanings of the word *direct*?

Answer (score 1):

There are two options.

1. It was intended as **"manage, control"** in the general sense. From the vantage point of a multilingual awareness (= if we know things about other, exotic languages), we can better manage our use of (plain) English, as opposed to an Anglocentric vantage point.
2. It was intended as **"conduct [an orchestra]"**, a metaphor. Then our own English is an orchestra that we lead to produce pleasant and efficient language from, and we have a better overview of our orchestra if we stand on the vantage point of a multilingial awareness.

Ultimately, the two interpretations lead to a similar general meaning of the quotation.